# zend framework basepath

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing, base-path

hi i have a web application installed in a remote server i wanted to modify this web application so i downloaded all the files from the server

.zfproject
library folder
application folder
public_html folder

and i created a folder called newZend in my local xampp\htdocs folder

when i tried to access the website 
"http://localhost/newZend/public"

it gives me an application error saying
script 'login/index.phtml' not found in path (C:/xampp/htdocs/newZend/application/modules/user/views\scripts/)

i believe something might be wrong with the url router or base path..please help

Comment: Is the backslash in `views\scripts/` a typo? Otherwise that might be the source of your problem.

Comment: @DilanSamarakkody Can you confirm that there actually is a file located at `C:/xampp/htdocs/newZend/application/modules/user/views\scripts/login/index.phtml`?  PHP will handle `/` vs `\` so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: yeah it this there... this is system is perfectly working on the remort server...itz just not working on my local machine :(

Answer (score 0):

The standard Zend Framework .htaccess rules and routes will take the url you gave

> when i tried to access the website "http://localhost/newZend/public"

and call for the "index" action of the "public" controller.

None of my Zend apps allow access directly to the public directory. Try this url:

> http://localhost/newZend

which will call the index action of the index controller.